# JavaFX - Set focus border for Textfield using CSS

Tags: javafx

I want to have a textfield with three different borders for three cases:

- a white border when not hovered or focused
- a grey border when hovering
- a blue border when focused and typing

I started like this:

```
#custom-text-field  {
    -fx-border-width: 2;
    -fx-border-color: white;
}

#custom-text-field:hover{
    -fx-border-width: 2;
    -fx-border-color: #909090;
}

#custom-text-field:focused{
    -fx-border-width: 2;
    -fx-border-color: #0093EF;
}
```

The problem is that the border for focusing never shows up. How do it set it correctly?

Comment: Do other css selectors work as expected?

Comment: The standard and the hover style work as expected.

Comment: Are you still seeing the default blue focus highlighting when your text field has focus? You may want to try using "-fx-focus-color".

Answer (score 3):

I use it like this

```
.custom-text-field {
    -fx-background-color:
        #FFFFFF,
        #FFFFFF;
    -fx-background-insets: 0, 2;
    -fx-background-radius: 0, 0;
 }

.custom-text-field:focused {
    -fx-background-color:
        #0093EF,
        #FFFFFF;
}

.custom-text-field:hover {
    -fx-background-color:
        #909090,
        #FFFFFF;
}

.custom-text-field:focused:hover {
    -fx-background-color:
        #0093EF,
        #FFFFFF;
}
```

Comment: I don't think `background-color` sets the `border`!

Comment: @lulian -fx-background-insets does as it is defined in .custom-text-field class and the pseudo-classes do the color manipulation for hover, focused and hover + focused.

Comment: you saved my day champ